# Proof the equal of state in Coq

Tags: coq

I have a data type **snapshot = (nat, state, bool)** in Coq. I want to write a function **beq_snap** to compare two snapshots and return a **bool** type.

```
Inductive id : Set := 
| Id : nat -> id.

Definition state := id -> nat.

Definition snapshot := nat * state * bool.
```

Comment: What is the purpose of the `state` and `snapshot` types?
Since `state` is a function type, instances of it cannot be compared under `bool`.

Comment: @mpetruska I want to use `state` to denote the value of the variables, so I use the `id` as the variable and `state` as the function from variable to value. since the function cannot be compared,  I consider to use the pair `(variable, value)`, and a list of pairs as the set of variables and values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend implementing state in a somewhat different way:

```
Require Import Bool.

Inductive id : Set := 
| Id : nat -> id.

Definition state : Set := list (id * nat).

Definition snapshot : Set := nat * state * bool.

Definition id_eqb (a b : id) : bool :=
  match a, b with
  | Id n1, Id n2 => Nat.eqb n1 n2
  end.

Fixpoint list_eqb (A : Set) (f : A -> A -> bool) (a b : list A) {struct a} : bool :=
  match a, b with
  | cons e1 t1, cons e2 t2 => andb (f e1 e2) (list_eqb A f t1 t2)
  | _         , _          => false
  end.

Arguments list_eqb [A].

Definition tuple_eqb (A B : Set) (fa : A -> A -> bool) (fb : B -> B -> bool) (a b : (A * B)) : bool :=
  match a, b with
  | (a1, a2), (b1, b2) => andb (fa a1 b1) (fb a2 b2)
  end.

Arguments tuple_eqb [A B].

Definition state_eqb : state -> state -> bool := list_eqb (tuple_eqb id_eqb Nat.eqb).

Notation "x /b\ y" := (andb x y) (at level 50).

Definition beq_snap (a b : snapshot) : bool :=
  match a, b with
  | (n1, s1, b1), (n2, s2, b2) => Nat.eqb n1 n2 /b\ state_eqb s1 s2 /b\ Bool.eqb b1 b2
  end.
```

Notice that `state` is defined as `list (id * nat)`.
(Maybe it's just me, but I did not find predefined functions to compare tuples and lists, so I defined them by hand. Anyone knows a better way?)

Comment: For lists you can use `list_eq_dec`, which returns a sumbool. This is often just as well because you can still do `if list_eq_dec l1 l2 then ... else ...` and it's convenient in proofs. I don't see anything for tuples in the standard library, but if you want to write a comparison that returns a sumbool you should check out the `decide equality` tactic (https://coq.inria.fr/refman/tactics.html#hevea_tactic188).

Comment: You can also use `Scheme Equality for list.` that creates two functions `list_eq_dec` and `list_beq`.

Answer (score 2):

Your `state` type is isomorphic to `nat -> nat`, and you can't write a function that compares such functions in Coq. The intuition behind this is to consider how such a comparison would work: if it terminates and concludes two states are equal, then it has only examined some finite portion of the two functions, and the remaining values of the states may or may not differ. Thus it is impossible to in finite time conclude that two states are equal (though if they differ, checking each index will eventually find one where they differ).